# How to take an int from file in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have file with many integers.

```
1
2
3
etc
```

And I want to write them in array. I use QFile for operations with files. So, do anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In [Details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#details) section, there is an example of using `QTextStream`.

Then use [QTextStream &QTextStream::operator>>(int &i)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-gt-gt-4) to read your `int`s.